# What class of functions can be applied to both sides of an equal sign and preserve the equality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are there some functions which cannot be applied to algebraic manipulation?

[Edit: I've ascertained so far that if $f(x)=1/x$ or $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $f(x)=\log_{b} x$ then you have to make sure that $x$ is non-zero in the first case, real in the second case, and natural number for the last case.]

Comment: with natural number you mean positive?

Comment: @Ant: Yes.  Though I was once taught that only integers greater than zero were natural.  I count 0 as natural after the development of Arabic numbers.

Comment: I meant, there are numbers like $\frac 34$ and $\sqrt 2$ which are positive but not integers

Answer (score 4):

For this question, if we speak only of “function”, we’re missing half the point. We also have to speak of the meaning of the equals sign, “$=$”. In almost all cases in mathematics, when we say “$A=B\,$”, we are not talking about two things, we are saying that “$A$” and “$B\,$” are two different names for *the same thing*. That is, “$A=B\,$” is not saying two things are in some sort of relation with each other, it’s saying that $A$ and $B$ are one and the same thing.

Accordingly, if we do have a genuine function $f$ and $A$ is in its domain, the implication “$A=B\Longrightarrow f(A)=f(B)$” is mathematically contentless: it’s a tautology.

Comment: Excellent distinction.  Now if I may suggest that the equal sign used for real numbers (like that in the physical sciences) is not the same equal sign used for arithmetic.  Because in sciences you never have the exact same thing, as it deals with the imperfect realm of MEASURE and you're always COMPARING with the equal sign, not putting a different name on it.  See also my question "What should the domain in which geometry exists be called?"

Comment: Nice point. From the standpoint of both physics and computer science, it is almost always impossible to say whether two real numbers are equal, unless of course they both have come to us out of pure mathematics.

Comment: Well I come from computer science, and I can say that most use, apart from scientific computing and floating point, is of pure mathematics, so you can say whether they are equal with absolute precision.  That's why it's interesting.

Answer (score 3):

A function is a relation whose fundamental property is: Equal inputs yield equal outputs.

This means that if you plug the same input into a function twice in a row, it'll give the same answer both times.

Here's an example of something that's **not** a function: "Time of day in $x$".
If you ask, "Time of day in New York" right now you'll get 12:55pm. However, if you ask again "Time of day in New York" you'll get 1pm. Different answers! Not a function.

Another example: Let $N(x)$ be the numerator of a fraction. This too is not a function. $N(4/2)=4$ but $N(10/5)=10$ however, $4/2=10/5$. So equal inputs, did not yield equal answers.

In the end the answer to your question might be kind of unsatisfying. Basically, you can apply any function to an equation and get an equation (as long as the left and right hand side of the equation lie in the domain of the function). In fact, this is essentially what we mean by the word "function".

Comment: But some functions, given an input, fail (divide by 0).  If you don't know the value of x to know that the function is satisfactory there, then you couldn't use it.

Comment: In the context of real numbers division by a particular  nonzero real number is a function and thus preserves equality. On the other hand division by zero is never defined so because it's not even defined it's not a function.

Comment: Now domain of definition is a related issue. For example if x = -1 then it isn't true that ln(x) = ln(-1) because logs aren't defined for negative numbers (well real valued logs anyway).

Answer (score 3):

If $x = y$ then $f(x) = f(y)$ for any function $f$.

*BUT* be careful that if the function is not one-to-one.  You will lose information.

For instance:  if $x = y$ and $x \ne -y$, we can square both sides and get $x^2 = y^2$.  But now we've lost the information that $x \ne -y$.  Or if $\theta = \phi + 6\pi$ then $\sin \theta = sin (\phi + 6\pi)= \sin \phi$.  Information is lost.

Likewise we must never be misdirected by the inverse of a non-one-to-one function on a restricted range.  If $x^2 = y^2$ we *can* conclude $\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{y^2}$ but that means $|x| = |y|$ and *not* $x = y$.  Likewise if you know $\sin x = \sin y$ than we know $\arcsin \sin x = \arcsin \sin y$ but that doesn't mean $x = y$. It means $x = \{y + 2k\pi, (2k+1)\pi - y\}$

But, yes, if $x =y$ you can *always* conclude that $f(x) = f(y)$ (for what it's worth).

=====

You seem to be concerned about using f(x) when f is not defined at x.  If f is not defined at f you get the not untrue statement undefined = undefined.  But this not untrue statement loses *all* information.

Example:  Let a = b = 1.

$a^2 = b^2$;  ($f(x) = x^2$ True, but we've just lost the information that $a \ne -b$.  Any conclusion we reach about a and b must include the possibility a = -b)

$a^2 - b^2 = 0$;  ($f(x) = x - b^2$ True, and we've lost no information)

$(a - b)(a + b) = 0$; (true, but this has nothing to do with applying functions)

$(a+b) = 0/(a - b) = 0$; (if $f(x) = x/(a-b) = x/0$; this isn't a function; but if  $f(x,y) = x/y$ then if $w = v$ we *can* do $f(w, q) = f(v, q)$ *but* as q = a - b = 0, it is true but we have just lost *all* information.  Any conclusion we reach can not be justified.)

$a + b = 1 + 1= 2 = 0$.

So $2 = 0$.  Q.E.D.;  (not true because we lost *all* information.  What we actually have is "undefined is undefined".)

Comment: Interesting.  I'm starting to see where the question really lies and it is at the entire notion of "equals".  In my working definition, you can't have undefined=undefined--it's a contradiction, and might be something like infinity=infinity.  But I think I can relax the notion.  Will ponder further...

Answer (score 1):

Any function works. That is, if you apply it to both sides of an inequality, you still get something that is true; that's because of the very definition of function, $f(x)$ can only take one value; so if $x=y$ necessarily $f(x) = f(y)$

The converse is not true though; that is, from $f(x) = f(y)$ you can't conclude $x=y$. The functions for which this is true are called injective;

The division by zero is not defined, it's not even a function; it is nothing.

So if you have a variable $x$ which may be $0$, you can't divide by $x$ because you can't be sure that the operation you are using (division ) is defined (it is not if $x=0$)

Comment: But what if for some value x, f(x) is undefined?  And we don't know beforehand that one side equals the other when solving some equations.

Comment: @MARXOS Of course $f(x)$ should be defined. If there are some values of $x$ for which $f(x)$ is not defined (like in the case of division by $0$) that you can't do that (or you have to treat those cases separetely). You are right regarding the second point, but that is not what you asked; you asked when $x=y \implies f(x) = f(y)$ and the answer is for any function. When solving some equation you need both directions; that is you need $x=y \iff f(x) = f(y)$ (so that you can apply $f$ and find the correct answer to the original question). And those functions are the injective ones.